# How to check image download time in ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs

I want to monitor the image download time when a new deployment is ran. I saw that the task event  details in the ECS console can give me a rough estimate, but I cannot really tell if the time consumed is image download time or something else. I would also like to know if it's using the cached image or from the remote repository. Is there a way to do this? Please help

Answer (score 1):

> But I cannot really tell if the time consumed is image download time or something else

Not sure if you can calculate the image pull time from AWS ECS events as  I did not find this in [ECS event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html), but one of the simplest approaches that you can try is to pull image manual on your ECS instance that will give some better estimate by using `time` with `docker pull`.

```
time docker pull alpine
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
Digest: sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321
Status: Image is up to date for alpine:latest

real    0m5.789s
user    0m0.033s
sys 0m0.039s
```

> I would also like to know if it's using the cached image or from the remote repository. Is there a way to do this?

You can control this behaviour using `ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR` this ECS variable, as by default it will pull image each time, so you can use `prefer-cached` if you want to improve launch time.

**ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR**

```
Example values: default | always | once | prefer-cached
```

Default value on Linux: default

Default value on Windows: default

> The behavior used to customize the pull image process for your
> container instances. The following describes the optional behaviors:
>
> If **default** is specified, the image is pulled remotely. If the
> image pull fails, then the container uses the cached image on the
> instance.
>
> If **always** is specified, the image is always pulled remotely. If
> the image pull fails, then the task fails. This option ensures that
> the latest version of the image is always pulled. Any cached images
> are ignored and are subject to the automated image cleanup process.
>
> If **once** is specified, the image is pulled remotely only if it has
> not been pulled by a previous task on the same container instance or
> if the cached image was removed by the automated image cleanup
> process. Otherwise, the cached image on the instance is used. This
> ensures that no unnecessary image pulls are attempted.
>
> If **prefer-cached** is specified, **the image is pulled remotely if
> there is no cached image. Otherwise, the cached image on the instance
> is used**. Automated image cleanup is disabled for the container to
> ensure that the cached image is not removed.

[ecs-agent-config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html)

[amazon-ecs-adds-options-to-speed-up-container-launch-times](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/05/amazon-ecs-adds-options-to-speed-up-container-launch-times/)